# Unable to Add external Server Tomcat In Netbeans 7.1

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am going to add Tomcat server in Netbeans 7.1 , it shows:

```
The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.
```

[image: The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.]

Can any body explain this?

Comment: I found an answer [here](http://razius.com/articles/installing-and-adding-an-external-tomcat-server-in-netbeans/)...it worked for me

Comment: To people getting here from Google: Try updating your Netbeans to the latest version. You might be using an old version of Netbeans that doesn't support your version of Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you did not specify the correct path. Maybe looking at [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AddExternalTomcat) Netbeans Wiki Page on how to add Tomcat as an External server might help.

Comment: @Nishant: CATALINA_HOME is the directory in which Tomcat is installed. For instance if you extracted your Tomcat.rar file in a directory called E:\, then CATALINA_HOME should be: CATALINA_HOME=E:\Tomcat\. Please check online for more information on this.

Answer (score 5):

CATALINA_HOME refers to the root directory of Tomcat.  This is often set as a sytem variable along with JAVA_HOME, the location of your jdk.

When netbean asks for a path to your Tomcat server, give it the root path of your Tomcat installation, not the bin directory.

Answer (score 3):

This is what it is looking for:
D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22

Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the information needed was giving looking on the "It works!" page that serves Tomcat by default at `localhost:8080`.

It mentioned the CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE locations, which in my case where:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7
```

Entering both paths on the Netbeans dialog did the work.

NOTE: if you see the following warning is because you need to also add the CATALINA_BASE path, not only the home.

[image: The <CATALINA_HOME>/conf/server.xml can't be read.]

---

You may still have troubles with the credentials

[image: Cannot lock read-only file /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml]

To solve this new problem just add a new user into the mentioned file and try again.

This error is because the file can only be written by the Root user, not Netbeans. And because of this, it's not recommendable to use the `Create user if it does not exist` option.

---

For more information checkout [the Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/tomcat.html#tomcat-configuration) and [this Netbeans thread](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AddExternalTomcat#Installing_and_Setting_up).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to chown the tomcat directory -

```
    sudo chown -R username:username /opt/tomcat-8/
```

Because I had set the owner and group to tomcat.  Alternately adding my user to the tomcat group works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting:

> The specified Server location(catalina home) folder not valid

error, it simply means you have not specified the correct directory to the tomcat,

**Right click on Servers in your Netbean->Add server-> Apache Tomcat or TomcatEE->Next->Browse**
*So when you navigate to the the extracted folder of the tomcat make sure you click it one more time to get into the root directory and the error will disappear*, **then click finish.**

Answer (score 0):

`Netbeans 12.0 apache-tomcat-8.5.60`

this will give you the `catalina.home` directory

`ps aux | grep catalina`

`catalina.home=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.60`

`catalina.base=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.60`

chown the tomcat directory worked for me

`sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/tomcat/`