# Not able to install Tomcat9 to Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat9

Need some help. Its my first time with netBeans and i am trying to install Tomcat server9 with netbeans 8.0.2. 
I am succesfully using it with eclipse but 
I googled ofcourse but none of the solution seemed to work. My CATALINA_HOME is set and pointing to tomcat location. In Path i added %CATALINA_HOME%\bin
But when i try to add it in netbeans  It gives the error:
" The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.
Can someone please help me 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Add external Server Tomcat In Netbeans 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545839/unable-to-add-external-server-tomcat-in-netbeans-7-1)

Comment: Is it possible to provide a screenshot of the error, and the actual value of CATALINA_HOME?