# why i can't add Tomcat 9 to Netbeans 8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-8

why i can't add Tomcat 9 to Netbeans 8 it always give a error message "The specified server location(Catalina Home) folder is not valid but I can add Tomcat 8.5.3.1

[image]

Comment: Are you using Netbeans 8.2?

Comment: No Netbeans 8.0

Comment: In 8.2 works, is updating an option?

Comment: ok dear I'ii try.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Add external Server Tomcat In Netbeans 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9545839/2985643). If that doesn't help, try wrapping your value of **Server Location** with double quotes just in case the spaces in your file path are an issue. I just added Tomncat 9.02 to NetBeans 8.2 with no problem.